# Proving equivalent definitions of continuity (open sets)

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

I want to prove the following statement:
If $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} $, a function $f\colon A\to \mathbb{R}^{m} $ is continuous if and only if for every open
set $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m} $ there exists some open set $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} $ s.t. $f ^{-1}(U)=V \cap A$.

I have already shown the *only if* part. My attempt for the *if* part goes as follows:

We have to find some $\delta(a)$ s.t. the following implication holds:
\begin{align*}
\forall x \in A\colon  \left\|x-a\right\| < \delta \implies \left\|f(x)-f(a)\right\| <\epsilon
.\end{align*}
We consider the open set $B_{\epsilon}\left(f(a)\right) $. By our initial assumption there must exist some open set $V$ s.t.
$f ^{-1}\left(B_{\epsilon}\left(f(a)\right)\right) = V \cap A.$ However, my problem is now that $V \cap A$ is not guaranteed to be open, since in the theorem $A$ is not necessarily open (if $A$ was open I could find some open ball around and the proof would be done).

Could someone give me a hint what I can do in order to conclude the proof?

Comment: $A$ **is** open for metric defined on $A$.

Comment: @Lab I don't understand what you mean. In the theorem it does't say that $A$ is necessarily open.

Comment: Posting it as an answer since it's a bit too long to put as a comment.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You want to say $V \cap A$ is open in order to contain a ball in it, but it is not necessary since you only have to check elements in $A$($\forall x \in A$).

So for any $x \in A$, if we have $x \in V$, by $f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(f(a))) = V \cap A$ it's guaranteed that $f(x) \in B_\epsilon(f(A))$. Hence proved.

What I was saying in the comment about "$A$ is open for metric defined on $A$" is that you can define a metric $d$ on $A$ that shares the same output **but is only defined on $A$**. In that case you can say $A$ is open because you only have to check the points in $A$.